# Keyboard has become slower over time on Windows Phone 10

Tags: keyboard

I notice that over time my keyboard has become worse at predicting text completions or next word suggestions. I remember it being much faster.

What can I do to get it back to original speed? Preferably without reinstalling or resetting the whole phone.

Windows Phone 10 on Lumia 550

Answer (score 1):

Another cause for this is when the phones internet connection is on, but not very good. I think there are some internet requests being made on the background that are failing and causes the typing to get slow especially when the paragraphs get longer. Going into flight mode temporarily seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

I find that under 
Settings - Keyboard - More Keyboard Settings - 
There is a a check box to select "Send Microsoft info about how I write...."

I find that turning this off helped.  Perhaps their logging was starting to get clogged up and slowed things down.

Comment: Your solution alone did not worked for me in the past, I've also had to reset mine. Maybe some sort of cache was still hanging around. I leave this just for the sake of completeness.